# The question list page URL has inconsistent variables

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, sorting, pagination

When on [the question list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions) you can click to sort by votes, activity, date, etc. You can also click to show 15, 30, or 50 questions per page.

The problem is that when you click on these they add variables to the URL and reload, naturally, but they do so inconsistently, sometimes leaving you with a URL that would not load what you are seeing if you copied it as a link.

For example, if I wanted to load page three, sorted by activity, at 30 entries per page the URL would need to be appended:

```
 ?page=3&sort=active&pagesize=30
```

But if I *navigate* to this page by clicking on active, then page three, then page size 30, I end up with an incomplete variable list:

```
 ?sort=active&pagesize=30
```

which if copied and pasted will not be the original page that I was looking at. If I click active, then page size 30 first, then page 3, I end up with:

```
 ?page=3&sort=active
```

which may possible load differently for some users, depending on their last used settings.

I'm sure this can be easily fixed.

---

I realize the question list changes frequently depending on settings, but sometimes it's pretty constant (e.g. page 2, sorted by votes, 50 page size).

Related thing: it would be nice if the page variable had a last and first argument.